# I need to pass queryparameters to my service endpoint but queryparameter id contains the ./ values so it could not reach to the service

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax

In this method i get the tag name and tag id but my id starts with./s89we so it could not reach to service. i want to open my content in new window. Find below url after used tag name and tag id,

../../Service.svc/export/plant?tag=tegtext&id=./s89

```
 $('#refplantexport').live("click", function () {
        $("#lblMessage").html('');
        var plant = $("#referenceMappingPlanttree").dynatree("getActiveNode");
        if (plant !== null && plant !== undefined) {
            var tag = plant.data.tag;
            var id = plant.data.id;
            var dictionary = plant.toDict();
            var channelid = dictionary.channelId;
            if (channelid !== undefined && channelid !== null && channelid !== "") {
                ShowSuccessMsg("Plant Items(s) Exported successfully");
                //escape('?key=value1&key2=value2');
                // var url = '../../Service.svc/export/plant/' + encodeURIComponent(id);
                var url = '../../Service.svc/export/plant?tag=' + tag + '&id=' + encodeURIComponent(id);

                //window.open(url, 'ExportChartDataCSV', 'left=20,top=20,width=400,height=400,toolbar=1,resizable=0', '');
                //jQuery.post(url, {parameters}, function(data, status){}, "text");
                exportToCSV(tag, id);
        }
```

after this i want i send ajax post.

```
function exportToCSV(tag, id) {

        $.ajax({
            url: '../../Service.svc/export/plant',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: JSON.stringify({ "tag": tag, "id": id }),
            complete: function (xhr, textStatus) {
                //called when complete
            },
            success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
                //called when successful
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                //called when there is an error
            }
        });
    }
```

this is my service endpoint

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/export/plant", Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
string ExportPlantData(string tag, string id);
```

Comment: I am facing similar kind of problem you just change `data: JSON.stringify({ "tag": tag, "id": id })` to `data: JSON.parse({ "tag": tag, "id": id })`